# Error in Cordova for Android: JDK/Android Target

Tags: android, cordova

Here's what I got when checking requirements:

```
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\app>cordova requirements
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 14.0.2
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed C:\Users\Ben\Downloads\gradle-6.6-all\gradle-6.6\bin\gradle.BAT
Some of requirements check failed
```

Here's what I got when trying to build:

```
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\app>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 14.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

I have set my environment variables for ANDROID_HOME to C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2, and add added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin, sdk tools, sdk platform tools, and Gradle Bin to my PATH.

Also, I have Android Studio with SDK tool for 9.0 and 10.0+ installed.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue (on Windows 10), and was able to solve it with these fixes:

1. Check which environment paths are providing you with `java` by running `for /F "tokens=*" %i in ('where java') do ("%i" -version)`. The first one is the most important, but if you see lots of different versions you might want to clean up your environment variables.
2. Make sure you have the *JDK* for Java ***8*** (aka. 1.8.x) installed. If not you'll have to do that first. Mine ended up in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`.
3. Make sure your *system* environment variable isn't including java in the **PATH** or it will be hard to override it at the *account* level.
4. Edit your *account's* **PATH** so it includes `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Remove any other paths to java.
5. Edit your *account's* **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to point to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201`. If you just want to do a quick test you can run `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201` in the command line.
6. Add an **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** account environment variable pointing to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` (with your *username*). I don't think this is strictly needed with this version, but seems this is recommended over using **ANDROID_HOME** for the future.
7. Don't forget to restart your command prompt anytime you make an environment variable change. Test with `@echo %JAVA_HOME% && @echo %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT% && where java`.
8. `cordova requirements` now gives happy "installed" responses for each item.
9. `cordova build android` should now work.